# Use local image in the cluster that skaffold is connected to

Tags: docker, kubernetes, skaffold

Assuming I have the following `skaffold.yaml`

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta12
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: myapp
build:
  local:
    push: true
  artifacts:
  - image: pkaramol/my-image
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: myapp
        chartPath: charts
  kubectl:
    manifests:
       - ./k8s/*
```

How can I instruct `skaffold` to avoid uploading (and then downloading) `pkaramol/myimage` to dockerhub but rather build it locally and using it directly within the cluster I am connected to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instruct Skaffold to build the image locally by using the `local` build mode in the `build` section of the skaffold.yaml file, like this:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta12
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: myapp
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
  - image: pkaramol/my-image
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: myapp
        chartPath: charts
  kubectl:
    manifests:
       - ./k8s/*
```

The `push` parameter should be set to `false` to prevent Skaffold from uploading the image to a registry. This will tell Skaffold to build the image locally and use it directly in the cluster that you are connected to.